# Angular2: @HostBinding or host: {}?

Tags: angular, animation, host

I was wondering if there was a drastic difference (and if there is, what is it?) between using `@HostBinding` and the `host` attribute of the component ?

I have been asking myself that question while I was using animations because I was in these cases (which look rather close) :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  animations: [
    trigger('myTransition', [
      state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])],
  host: {
    '[@myTransition]': '',
   },
})
```

OR

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  animations: [
    trigger('myTransition', [
      state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])],
})

export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('@myTransition') get myTransition() {
    return '';
  }
}
```

I then thought that it my might be the new way of host binding.

Thanks in advance for your advice and input ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The official guidance is to prefer HostListener/HostBinding

from the [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03)

> HostListener/HostBinding decorators versus host metadata
>
> Style 06-03 Consider preferring the @HostListener and @HostBinding to
>   the host property of the @Directive and @Component decorators.
>
> Do be consistent in your choice.
>
> Why? The property associated with @HostBinding or the method
>   associated with @HostListener can be modified only in a single
>   place—in the directive's class. If you use the host metadata property,
>   you must modify both the property declaration inside the controller,
>   and the metadata associated with the directive.

However, the angular/material2 project [says to prefer "host"](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS.md)

> Host bindings
>
> Prefer using the host object in the directive configuration instead of
>   @HostBinding and @HostListener. We do this because TypeScript
>   preserves the type information of methods with decorators, and when
>   one of the arguments for the method is a native Event type, this
>   preserved type information can lead to runtime errors in non-browser
>   environments (e.g., server-side pre-rendering).

Comment: I also have noticed this contradiction

Answer (score 3):

Both are equivalent.
In ES5 where decorators are not available, you can use `host: {}`

Comment: Okay so it is just another way of using host binding, exactly like the input: [] and the @Input?

Comment: Yes, everything that's available with decorators is available in `host` and vice versa.

Comment: are they really equivalent?
I currently have the problem where they lead to different behavior. `host` works while `@HostBinding` doesn't work.
I actually wanted to something like -> https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts 
It's interesting even angular uses host despite its guidelines

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. Might be worth a new question with a repo in StackBlitz or similar.

Comment: I added the question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942849/host-and-hostbinding-leads-to-different-behavior

Would be very interested in why this behavior is observed