# host and @HostBinding leads to different behavior

Tags: angular

I need to able to run some "pseudo-validation" in angular. That means our customer wants "validation" that displays as warning but it is still valid in angular terms.

For that I use angular's form validation (because it seems the proper way to go).

I created a directive which updates the css class of its host, similar to what [angular itself does](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts)

After spending ours of trying out different things (always with `@HostBinding`) I noticed the class never gets added when using `@HostBinding` but works successfully when using the directive's `host`

See the stackblitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keky2p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

the goal is to render orange as background of the input.
if you use `host` it works, if you use `@HostBinding` it doesn't.

the function `asWarning` just makes any provided validator always return NULL (valid)

They should be equivalent, yet there seems to be some differences.
Am I doing something wrong or are they not equivalent?

Comment: I don't get what differences I should see. There is no need to introduce a field. You can add `@HostBinding(...)` to `get displayWarning() {..`

Comment: man, after spending hours, I seem to have made a very stupid mistake...
in my example `getDisplayWarning` will be executed way too early.

if you add your comment as an answer I mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to introduce a field.
You can add `@HostBinding(...)` to `get displayWarning() {...`